# How to monitor wifi network connection from raspi to linux PC

Tags: wifi, linux, compute-module-3

I have several raspberry pi CM 3B+ in a custom device. I use USB dongle as wifi adapter.
After some time passed, the connection became unstable and it often cannot even reconnect and need to be restarted. I am troubleshooting this and I think overheating is the problem. I change it to power save mode and I want to compare the result between before and after changing the power save mode. Is there a tool that I can use in my Linux Ubuntu desktop to gather information about this? Usually I just ping the device from my desktop and check it after sometimes. I check the package loss and the timing of each ping. I hope there would be more convenient tool to check this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you could set up each pi to periodically run 'iwconfig' and dump output into an html file, (like with a cron job or boot up script) then have a simple web server  running on each pi, like nginx. connect to each pi from the desktop and retrieve the html data. (you could also dump the output of vcgencmd measure_temp )